# Combination Theory Problem: Whole Numbers between 1000 and 9999 whose digits sum up to 9

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

Given the following problem:

> How many whole numbers between 1000 and 9999 fulfill the following
> conditions
>
> - The sum of it's digits is exactly 9.
> - The sum of it's digits is exactly 9 and they are all different from 0.

I understand the concept of the question from which I know that I will be working with four digits and believe that I am to use the total amount of numbers between that interval which is $9999 - 1000 = 8999$.

If I am correct, it appears that the total number of possibilities will be $\binom{8999}{4}$. Would that be correct?

And how I proceed from here?

Comment: The answer clearly is less than $9000$ and $\binom{8999}{4}$ is way larger.

Comment: The answer to the first point is the coefficient of $x^9$ in $$(x+x^2+\ldots+x^9)(1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^9)^3$$ and the answer to the second point is the coefficient of $x^9$ in $$(x+x^2+\ldots+x^9)^4.$$ Both instances can be solved through [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a "stars and bars" problem.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

You have some number of digits to work with and a set of bins to distribute them across.

The digits you are free to distribute are the stars.

The separation between the bins are the bars.

a)

You must put at least 1 star in the first bin.  That leaves 8 that you are free to allocate.

8 stars and 3 bars

${11\choose 3} = 165$

b)
No zeros.  1 star in each bin.

5 stars 3 bars

${8\choose 3} = 56$

Answer (score 2):

By [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))

$$\left|\{(a,b,c,d)\in\mathbb{N}_+^4 : a+b+c+d=9\}\right|=\binom{8}{3}=56 $$
and this is the answer to the second point. The answer to the first point is
$$\begin{eqnarray*}&&[x^9](x+x^2+\ldots+x^9)(1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^9)^3\\&=&[x^8](1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^9)^4\\&=&[x^{12}](x+x^2+\ldots)\\&=&\left|\{(a,b,c,d)\in\mathbb{N}_+^4 : a+b+c+d=12\}\right|=\binom{11}{3}=165.\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Why is $a+b+c+d=12$ for the second part?

Comment: Because the coefficient of $x^m$ in $f(x)$ equals the coefficient of $x^{m+n}$ in $x^n f(x)$ and $8+4=12$.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want a way to proceed with the problem, you wouldn’t need the total number of possibilities. Here’s where you can begin to work out the problem:
The lowest number would be 1116 and the highest would be 6111 since the number can’t have any digits as 0s. After that you could list down the possibilities for every 1000 numbers that satisfy the conditions.

Comment: This is not a very efficient approach.

Comment: For the first part of the question, wouldn't the highest be 9000?